# Сервер не видит сервлет

Tags: hibernate, java-ee

Создал небольшое клиентское web-приложение на JavaEE  с использованием Hibernate- добавление,вывод клиентов. 
Создал сервлет,который выводит форму для добавления и вывода. Сделал маппинг web.xml

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>manager</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Hibernate.manager</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>manager</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/manager</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

В index.jsp делаю ссылку

```
<a href="manager">Менеджер событий</a>
```

Но сервер пишет ошибку

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:149)
    Hibernate.manager.doGet(manager.java:75)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.22 logs.
```

75 строка:

```
HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
```

Маппинг java-класса представления таблицы - xml разметка.

С удовольствием скину проект, если нужен весь проект.

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь!

Comment: В следующей раз вместо того, что-бы вставлять точки в теги - просто выделите ваш код и воспользуйтесь **волшебной кнопочкой 101010** :D

Comment: HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().begin(); делали?

Comment: использую HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().begingetTransaction();

Вставил Вашу,закоментив свою, не помогло...